# Time Machine says Time Capsule is full even though all backups are much smaller than HDD

Tags: finder, time-machine, backup, time-capsule

I have several machines backing up via Time Machine to a 1TB Time Capsule.

Lately one of my Macs said he had to delete an old backup in order to create the new backup. I was surprised about this since I formatted the whole Time Capsule not too long ago.

After I check the Time Capsule's network share, I selected all files in Finder, i.e. all machines' backups and opened the combined info panel. It told me that all files are only around 350GB big, which is much less than the capacity of the Time Capsule. 
I thought that maybe there are some hidden files so I checked in Terminal (`ls -a`) and there were no more files than in Finder (that would take up a lot of space).

When I went one level up in Finder and asked Finder for the info of the whole network drive, it told me that the capacity is indeed 1TB and only few GB are left on the disk.

How can I now find out what's wrong with the Time Capsule and what is apparently taking up space on it?

Comment: Are you sure that you can even access the content of the backups from other computers (try to drill down into these folders)? If you can't, Finder won't give you the correct size.

Comment: I actually can't read the other backups because they are encrypted but they are stored as an image, so technically it should still be possible to get the size of the image. I mean Finder lets me get all inidividual sizes of each backup and they make sense considering their respective hard drives and what they are being used for.